# Returning rows based on sum of column

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve a subset of data based on the sum of a column.  The goal is a script to release backordered items.  Say we have 100 BO products and get 50 in stock.  I'd like to update the oldest orders where the sum of order qty < 50.  So something like:

Sample Schema:

```
Orders Table:
order_id, order_date

order_products Table:
order_product_id, order_id, product_id, product_status, ordered_quantity


select * from products 
where products_id=1234 
and status=1 
and sum(products_qty) < 50;
```

Where sum(products_qty) is the total returned qty, not just for the individual row. Not sure if this is possible with a single query or even a subquery, but thought I would ask the experts here first.  I'm trying to avoid returning all the rows and then manually count up till I reach the limit.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using aggregate functions like `SUM()` and `COUNT()`, you can't use them in `WHERE` clauses. WHERE clauses are applied row-by-row as the database scans the table/indexes, which means that the results of the aggregate functions aren't available yet.

Filtering by aggregate results has to be done using `HAVING`, which is essentially done as the last step before returning data to the client.

From the sounds of your requirement, you need a running count to be kept, until you've retrieved enough rows/orders to use up the new product being entered. This can't be done with a single query. You'd need to use a server-side variable to keep track of how much product's been "used up" by the individual backorders.

Going off the top of my head, something like this might do the trick:

```
SET @Available = 50;

SELECT order_id, SUM(ordered_quantity), @Available := @Available - SUM(ordered_quantity) AS available
FROM order_products
WHERE product_id = XXX
GROUP BY order_id, product_id
HAVING available >= 0;
```

with whatever extra WHERE clauses so you get the oldest backorders first

Comment: That seems about right.  I have to bring in another table as well, so I've started on a PHP version of this.

Answer (score 2):

You need use GROUP by and Having

```
select * from products 
where products_id=1234 
and status=1 
group by YourGroupingFields
Having sum(products_qty) < 50;
```

based on your info:

```
select product_id from products 
where status=1 
group by product_id
Having sum(products_qty) < 50;
```

will be return product_id for which total quantity less 50

Comment: That's close - but I'm looking to return the first x rows of products up to where the total ordered quantity = 50.  So, that could be 50 rows if everyone ordered just 1 or 25 if everyone ordered 2, etc...